# VB 6 - remove/hide system shutdown counter | shutdown shell command

Tags: windows, shell, vb6, windows-xp, shutdown

IDE - VB 6.0

Testing System - Windows XP

I am using the shutdown shell command  `Shell ("shutdown -s -f -t 15")` to shut down the machine. The problem is when I executing the command a system shutdown counter is also appearing by default,  as you can see in the picture below

[image: img_shutdown_counter]

If I set `-t 00`, the system shutdown counter is not appearing but the machine is shutting down without any delay which I don't want.

**I want to wait 15 sec, also I want not to see this shutdown counter in the 15 sec waiting period.**

Any ideas, how I can achieve this?

Comment: Start a timer with 15 seconds that executes your shutdown command with -t 00 and hide your form.

Comment: Thanks man, really simple but effective idea. Why didn't I think this before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

Take a **Timer** control

> Properties of the Timer
>
> **Enabled -> True**
>
> **Interval -> 1000**

Code

```
Dim x As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
Timer1.Enabled = False
x = 15
End Sub

Private Sub btnShutdown_Click()
Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

x = x - 1

If x = 0 Then
Shell ("shutdown -s -f -t 00")
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks to @Steeeve for the hint.